# How to rig this Ornithopter Plane Toy Crank?

Tags: rigging

i really have no clue on how to rig this model.
hope you guys have some tricks or already knew about this.

https://pasteall.org/blend/6f6200bf8dbe4c37920baf3880bd2f01
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, how is it supposed to be animated?

Comment: it is same with crank shaft motion. wait a second, i will upload the gif.

Comment: please click on "accept answer" so other users although know that the answer helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

add a base bone, animate rotation.

add another bone with trackto to constraint to bone.003

add another bone, unparent it, move it as in picture. Add trackto constraint to bone.001.

result:

[image]

[image]

Note: Of course, bone.003 is just "one" wing. Do the same on the other side or use mirroring.

Lenghten Bone.001 to get a "lower" wing movement.

Animation from side view:

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

Moonboots (formerly known as Superman) was right as he stated in the comments that my rig has a dependency circle.

So i tried to fix it:

new result:

[image]

new blend file:

[image]

Before: Bone1 hat trackto to bone3.
Bone3 hat trackto to bone1. That's bad. -> dependency circle

I know added another bone.

Now Bone1 has trackto bone3.
new Bone 4 has trackto Bone1
Bone3 has no constraints.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133038/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-how-to-rig-this-ornithopter-plane-toy-crank).

Comment: sorry guys for my late reply. i was asleep last night. anyway chris, is it possible to move the sphere thing on the bone.001 a little bit near the center? because the two planks in the front are going to move up and down following that bottom crank.

Comment: i already add more motion refferences by two pov. i made it using solidworks but it is really hard for me to figure out when using blender.

Comment: of course. Just lengthen/shorten the bones to your needs. Although i am not sure what center you mean, i think you should try to shorten bone.003